# Unable to get sed to replace commas with a word in my CSV

Tags: bash, csv, sed

Hello I am using bash to create CSV file by extracting data from an html file using grep. The problem is after getting the data then using sed to take out , in it and put a word like My_com it gose a crazy on me. here is my code.

```
time=$(grep -oP 'data-context-item-time=.*.data-context-item-views' index.html \
| cut -d'"' -f2)

title=$(grep -oP 'data-context-item-title=.*.data-context-item-id' index.html |\
cut -d'"' -f2)

sed "s/,/\My_commoms/g" $title
echo "$user,$views,$time,$title" >> test
```

I keep getting this error
    sed: can't read Flipping: No such file or directory
    sed: can't read the: No such file or directory
and so on

any advice on what wrong with my code

Comment: I would add an `echo "$title"` just before your `sed` command to be sure that it's processing what you think.

Comment: sed is trying to read a file named $title ..whatever is in that variable .... you probably need double quotes due to spaces in a file name, but would need more info to be sure

Comment: My value show up fine prior to adding the sed command. For some reason it only happen when my script runs though the sed command.

Comment: The variable in $title are youtube title names that I extracted from an html with grep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use sed on text directly on the command line like that; sed expects a file, so it is reading your text as a file name.  Try this for your second to last line:

```
echo $title | sed 's/,/My_com/g'
```

that way sed sees the text on a file (stdin in this case).  Also note that I've used single quotes in the argument to sed; in this case I don't think it will make any difference, but in general it is good practice to make sure bash doesn't mess with the command at all.

If you don't want to use the `echo | sed` chain, you might also be able to rewrite it like this:

```
sed 's/,/My_com/g' <<< "$title"
```

I think that only works in bash, not dash etc.  This is called a 'here-string', and bash passes the stuff on the right of the `<<<` to the command on its stdin, so you get the same effect.